# testing calling a function in another class with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Attempting to test this code:

```
def new_function
  begin
    m = MyModule::MyClass.new(@var1,@var2,@var3)
    m.my_function
  rescue Exception => e
    raise e
end
```

This is the test:

```
describe "#new_function" do
  let(:var1) { 'var1'}
  let(:var2) { 'var2'}
  let(:var3) { 'var3'}
  let(:m) { MyModule::MyClass.new(var1,var2,var3) }

  it "should run my_function in another class MyClass" do
    expect(m).to receive(:my_function).and_return(0)
  end
end
```

I am getting this error:

expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

> expected: 1 time with any arguments
>
> received: 0 times with any arguments

That is correct. All you do is set up the expectation and then... nothing. Don't you need to call that `new_function`?

Comment: So this doesn't test calling the new function?                            
    expect(m).to receive(:my_function).and_return(0)

Comment: No, this only sets up the expectation, and then you just don't call it.

Answer (score 1):

You've set an expectation, but never actually called the function. You can read more on stubbing [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value#specify-a-return-value)

This is how your method should look like instead:

```
describe "#new_function" do
  let(:var1) { 'var1'}
  let(:var2) { 'var2'}
  let(:var3) { 'var3'}
  let(:m) { MyModule::MyClass.new(var1,var2,var3) }

  it "should run my_function in another class MyClass" do
    expect(m).to receive(:my_function).and_return(0)
    m.my_function
  end
end
```

You also want to close that begin block:

```
  begin
    m = MyModule::MyClass.new(@var1,@var2,@var3)
    m.my_function
  rescue Exception => e
    raise e
  end
```